# Divison by Zero

Tags: divisibility

I have seen multiple answers on the web, but I can't get my mind around why division by zero outputs an error and not zero. Can anyone explain this in laymen's terms?

Comment: I bet this is a duplicate.

Comment: On that note, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87781/defining-division-by-zero), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by), [another one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801492/why-cant-we-divide-by-zero) and [one more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11161/why-does-x-divided-by-zero-not-equal-x)

Comment: @Cody Rutscher Basically, without going into all of the details, division by zero doesn't make sense. It is a question that doesn't have an answer. What is the color of the wind? Undefined.

Comment: Why on earth would it be $0$??? If $\frac ab = x$ then that means by definition that $bx = a$.  So if $\frac 50 = x$ would mean by definition that $0*x = 5$.  If $x = 0$ you get $0*0 = 5$ which is not true so $\frac 50 \ne 0$.  You'll have to try something else.  If $0*x = 5$ what is $x$.  If you can answer that you are done.  Can you answer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's try it. Let's divide $x$ by $0$ and say it's equal to some number $y$. Then

$$\frac x0=y.$$

By definition, we may multiply both sides by $0$, and see $x=y\cdot0=0$. This isn't true; we didn't assume $x$ to be zero. However, this tells us the only number we can divide by $0$ is $0$ itself; indeed, $\tfrac00=y$ doesn't result in a contradiction.

The problem with saying $\tfrac00$ is defined, is that it is everything at once. It doesn't have only one value. $\tfrac00=1$ wouldn't reach a contradiction (not by multiplying by $0$, that is) and neither would $\tfrac00=0$. In mathematics, we like things to only represent one thing and one thing only. If we would let $\tfrac00$ mean both $0$ and $1$ at the same time, then we wouldn't be able to use $=$ like we want; if we did, then

$$0=\frac00=1\implies 0=1$$

So, that would be a hassle for just letting this thing that is everything at once exist. Hence, we just agree to not divide by $0$, so we can keep all our rules, axioms, and theorems we know.